# expression must evaluate to a node-set

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I seem to be facing a pretty complex problem (at least complex to me). We have c# program which basically parses a schema file and spits out xmls. 
But now I have been tasked to modify this program to enable it to add a few more elements.

Let me try and explain.

As you can see in the figure below I have a schema file (have attached only part of it for convenience).

[image: Schema File]

The highlighted protion is what i am concered about i.e. USPhone,Extension,ForeignPhone. All three schema elements are under a Choice schema element and US Phone and Extension are underneath the sequence element.

Currently, for the highlighted portion, the xml that gets generated is as follows (Highlighted in yellow)

[image: Current XML Output]

I however would like to get the program to out put something like this

[image: Modified XmL Output]

i.e. Add new element which is a parent node to USPhone and Extension and a new e parent node to Foreign Phone, this is similar to ForeignAddress which has other elements underneath it.

While the program recursively goes through each of the schema objects, and spits out xml, when it comes to the Choice [XmlSchemaChoice], I create a new XMLSchemaElement (USPhoneNumberGrp) which is supposed to act as a parent node for USPhone and Extension elements. But the problem happens when I try to access this newly added parent node using

XmlNode parentNode = prototype.SelectSingleNode(path);

[prototype is an XMLDocument which has been created until now by parsing all the previous schema elements]

the path is currently having a value

path = "/PrototypeDocument/CAForm592B/WithholdingAgent/USPhoneNumberGrp"

but i get the following error "expression must evaluate to a node-set"

basically implying that the path itself is wrong although when i look at the XMLDocument (see below) generated so far I do see the newly added element USPhoneNumberGrp.

```
<PrototypeDocument>
<CAForm592B LineNumber="" Description="&quot;&quot;" Type="CAForm592BType" Documentation="&quot;CA Form 592-B - Resident and Nonresident Withholding Tax Statement&quot;" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="" documentName="CAForm592B">
<Amended MinOccurs="0" LineNumber="Top of Form" Description="&quot;Amended&quot;" Type="BooleanType" Documentation="&quot;Base type for a boolean. Typically used on an Yes or No field.&quot;" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="" />
<WithholdingAgent LineNumber="Part I" Description="&quot;Withholding agent&quot;" Type="WithholdingAgent" Documentation="" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="">
<Name LineNumber="" Description="&quot;Withholding agent's (payer's/S Corporation/Partnership's/LLC/Trust) name&quot;" Type="CA-BusinessNameType" Documentation="&quot;Type for a Business Name according to CA specifications.  Legal Characters: A-Z, a-z, 0-9, hash, hyphen, parentheses, ampersand, apostrophe and single space. Illegal Character: leading space, trailing space, adjacent spaces, and other symbols.&quot;" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="70" />
<IDNumber LineNumber="" Description="&quot;Identification Number&quot;" Type="IDNumber" Documentation="" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="">
<Individual ChoiceID="b7eaf17b-d515-48b4-b24f-0eb3e136273d" LineNumber="" Description="&quot;Individual identification number&quot;" Type="Individual" Documentation="" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="">
<SSN ChoiceID="746e28ef-3a82-4de6-b7d1-09a336474669" LineNumber="" Description="&quot;Social Security Number&quot;" Type="SSNType" Documentation="&quot;Type for Social Security No. - 9 digits&quot;" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="" />
<ITIN ChoiceID="746e28ef-3a82-4de6-b7d1-09a336474669" LineNumber="" Description="&quot;IRS Individual  Taxpayer Identification Number&quot;" Type="CA-ITINType" Documentation="&quot;CA type for Federal ITIN&quot;" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="" />
<NotApplicable ChoiceID="746e28ef-3a82-4de6-b7d1-09a336474669" LineNumber="" Description="&quot;Not applicable. ID number is individual in type and not applicable per a qualifying reason&quot;" Type="CA-NotApplicableType" Documentation="&quot;CA type for entity ID information to indicate that no Foreign entity Id or CA State Id number applies or exists.&quot;" Enum1="Foreign Non-US" Enum2="Applied For" ValidValuesForFields="Foreign Non-US;Applied For" MaxLengthOfFields="" />
</Individual>
<Other ChoiceID="b7eaf17b-d515-48b4-b24f-0eb3e136273d" LineNumber="" Description="&quot;Other business or non-individual identification number&quot;" Type="CA-BusinessIdType" Documentation="" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="">
<CACorporationNumber ChoiceID="87b268af-3e7a-4fd2-9cff-c2547f34ec17" LineNumber="" Description="&quot;California corporation number&quot;" Type="CA-CorporationNumberType" Documentation="&quot;Type for California corporation number&quot;" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="" />
<SOSNumber ChoiceID="87b268af-3e7a-4fd2-9cff-c2547f34ec17" LineNumber="" Description="&quot;California Secretary of State number&quot;" Type="CA-SOSNType" Documentation="&quot;Type for California Secretary of State file number&quot;" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="" />
<LLCTempNumber ChoiceID="87b268af-3e7a-4fd2-9cff-c2547f34ec17" LineNumber="" Description="&quot;Limited Liability Company temporary number&quot;" Type="CA-LLCTempNumberType" Documentation="&quot;CA type for LLC Temporary Number assigned by FTB&quot;" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="" />
<NotApplicable ChoiceID="87b268af-3e7a-4fd2-9cff-c2547f34ec17" LineNumber="" Description="&quot;Not Applicable per qualifying reason&quot;" Type="CA-NotApplicableType" Documentation="&quot;CA type for entity ID information to indicate that no Foreign entity Id or CA State Id number applies or exists.&quot;" Enum1="Foreign Non-US" Enum2="Applied For" ValidValuesForFields="Foreign Non-US;Applied For" MaxLengthOfFields="" />
<FEIN ChoiceID="87b268af-3e7a-4fd2-9cff-c2547f34ec17" LineNumber="" Description="&quot;Federal employee identification number&quot;" Type="EINType" Documentation="&quot;Type for Employer Identification No. - 9 digits&quot;" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="" />
</Other>
</IDNumber>
<USAddress ChoiceID="f97d374d-0961-4101-bdd0-85099615eb54" LineNumber="" Description="&quot;United States Address&quot;" Type="USAddressType" Documentation="" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="">
<AddressLine1Txt LineNumber="" Description="&quot;&quot;" Type="StreetAddressType" Documentation="&quot;Address line 1&quot;" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="35" />
<AddressLine2Txt MinOccurs="0" LineNumber="" Description="&quot;&quot;" Type="StreetAddressType" Documentation="&quot;Address line 2&quot;" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="35" />
<CityNm LineNumber="" Description="&quot;&quot;" Type="CityType" Documentation="&quot;City&quot;" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="22" />
<StateAbbreviationCd LineNumber="" Description="&quot;&quot;" Type="StateType" Documentation="&quot;State&quot;" Enum1="AL" Enum2="AK" Enum3="AS" Enum4="AZ" Enum5="AR" Enum6="CA" Enum7="CO" Enum8="MP" Enum9="CT" Enum10="DE" Enum11="DC" Enum12="FM" Enum13="FL" Enum14="GA" Enum15="GU" Enum16="HI" Enum17="ID" Enum18="IL" Enum19="IN" Enum20="IA" Enum21="KS" Enum22="KY" Enum23="LA" Enum24="ME" Enum25="MH" Enum26="MD" Enum27="MA" Enum28="MI" Enum29="MN" Enum30="MS" Enum31="MO" Enum32="MT" Enum33="NE" Enum34="NV" Enum35="NH" Enum36="NJ" Enum37="NM" Enum38="NY" Enum39="NC" Enum40="ND" Enum41="OH" Enum42="OK" Enum43="OR" Enum44="PW" Enum45="PA" Enum46="PR" Enum47="RI" Enum48="SC" Enum49="SD" Enum50="TN" Enum51="TX" Enum52="VI" Enum53="UT" Enum54="VT" Enum55="VA" Enum56="WA" Enum57="WV" Enum58="WI" Enum59="WY" Enum60="AA" Enum61="AE" Enum62="AP" ValidValuesForFields="See instructions for valid values" MaxLengthOfFields="" />
<ZIPCd LineNumber="" Description="&quot;&quot;" Type="ZIPCodeType" Documentation="&quot;ZIP code&quot;" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="" />
</USAddress>
<ForeignAddress ChoiceID="f97d374d-0961-4101-bdd0-85099615eb54" LineNumber="" Description="&quot;Foreign Address&quot;" Type="CA-ForeignAddressType" Documentation="" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="">
<StreetAddress LineNumber="" Description="&quot;Address line 1&quot;" Type="CA-StreetAddressType" Documentation="&quot;Type for a Street Address according to CA specifications&quot;" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="" /><InCareOfAddress MinOccurs="0" LineNumber="" Description="&quot;Address line 2&quot;" Type="CA-StreetAddressType" Documentation="&quot;Type for a Street Address according to CA specifications&quot;" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="" />
<City MinOccurs="0" LineNumber="" Description="&quot;City&quot;" Type="TextType" Documentation="&quot;Used for a text field. Legal Characters: printable characters from ! to ~ plus symbols from ¡ to ¿ plus Spanish characters and single space. Illegal Character: leading space, trailing space, adjacent spaces.&quot;" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="50" />
<Country LineNumber="" Description="&quot;Country&quot;" Type="CA-CountryType" Documentation="&quot;CA type for foreign address country which may include province and/or state&quot;" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="19" />
</ForeignAddress>
<USPhoneNumberGrp ChoiceID="2d3ce0ab-bc99-465f-a80c-b70dd0c9ebff" LineNumber="" Description="&quot;&quot;" Type="" Documentation="" ValidValuesForFields="" MaxLengthOfFields="" />
</WithholdingAgent>
</CAForm592B>
</PrototypeDocument>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong to get this error.

I hope you guys can help me out here.

Thanks,
AJ

Comment: If I load the XML in your question with `XmlDocument.LoadXml()`, then call `SelectSingleNode(path)` with the path you provide -- it works fine, there is no exception.  Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: This kind of job is so much easier to do in XSLT...